# HornetQ Persistence using MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, persistence, hornetq

HornetQ by default is using file system and it's own Journals for persistence , is it possible to change this default behaviour to use MS SQL server instead for the persistence ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, HornetQ only supports file persistence.

There isn't really a reason to support a database. Users usually only want a database for tradition. there isn't really any gain on having persistence on a message system through databases.

Comment: if there was a database support the fail over would have been easier , however here also we can use the SAN and point both instances to the same Journal . just wanted to make sure . thanks

Comment: We may add in the future as a lot of users are asking about it.
So far though I have seen users being happy about using only the journal after knowing HornetQ better.

Comment: Can you suggest any messaging API tool which persist Message in Database ?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis is underway with development.
ActtiveMQ 5 already does it